# d3.js and dimple, reading data in from a file rather than hard coded

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I'm trying to transition from a hard-coded version of a Dimple/D3 visualization which works well, and a more "dynamic" one that reads data in from a file, however, I'm finding it quite problematische.

Here is more or less what I'm going for:

[image]

Towards that aim, the following code works perfectly, i.e. it generates exactly that image you just saw:

```
<div id="chartContainer">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.1.1.min.js"></script>
</div>

<script>

console.log(data);

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 1000, 1000);
var data = [
          { '"loc"': '"Hamburg, Deutschland"', '"title"': "CNC-Dreher/in" },
          { '"loc"': 'M?nchen (Kreis), Bayern', '"title"': "Data Scientist" },
          { '"loc"': '"D?sseldorf, Nordrhein-Westfalen"', '"title"': "Praktikant m|w" },
          { '"loc"': '"Rheinland-Pfalz, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Senior Softwareentwickler Logistikdienstleistung(w/m)" },
          { '"loc"': '"D?sseldorf, Nordrhein-Westfalen"', '"title"': "Projektmanager (m/w) Information Engineering" },
          { '"loc"': '"Grimma, Leipzig (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Softwareentwickler (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Hannover, Region Hannover (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Bauleiter (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"M?nchen (Kreis), Bayern"', '"title"': "Backend Software Developer (m/f)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Ratingen, Mettmann (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Ausbildung Industriekaufmann (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Bayern, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Dualer Studiengang Bachelor of Arts (Fachrichtung Bank/Vertrieb) Bayern" },
          { '"loc"': '"Landshut, Landshut (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Spezialist CFK m/w" },
          { '"loc"': '"Frankfurt am Main, Hessen"', '"title"': "Data Analyst / Consultant analytisches CRM (m/w) f?r unseren Premium Partner EDEKA" },
          { '"loc"': '"Hamburg, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Produktmanager (m/w) im Bereich Privat Kraft" },
          { '"loc"': '"Unterf?hring, M?nchen (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Controller / Assistent der Gesch?ftsleitung" },
          { '"loc"': '"Berlin, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Projektmanager (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': 'Royal Leamington Spa', '"title"': "SOFTWARE TEST ENGINEER / QA (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Lauf an der Pegnitz, N?rnberger Land (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Bilanzbuchhalter/in" },
          { '"loc"': '"Buchenb?hl, N?rnberg"', '"title"': "Inhouse Business Intelligence Berater (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Berlin, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Praktikant Vertriebscontrolling (m/w) f?r die Dauer von 6 Monaten (Pflichtpraktikum)" }
        ];
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg,data);
chart.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 300);

var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", '"loc"');
var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", '"title"');

var lines = chart.addSeries(["project"], dimple.bar, [x, y]);

lines.data = data;
lines.lineWeight = 5;
lines.lineMarkers = true;

chart.draw();

</script>
```

However when I attempt to load the data from an external file ([link to said file on my GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/bookish-adventure/master/data/Germany.csv)), which is much much larger, (*with very similar characteristics as the toy data in the code above*) I get an error- or- in fact- I get a map that is essentially meaningless, here is photo of that despicable mess, followed by the code from the latest iteration of what I have been using:

[image]

In that one point `"loc"` is undefined and `"title"` is `0.0`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function draw(data) {

  "use strict";
  var margin = 75,
      width = 9000 - margin,
      height = 600 - margin;

  var svg = d3.select("body")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", width + margin)
              .attr("height", height + margin)
              .append('g')
              .attr('class','chart');


  var chart = new dimple.chart(svg,data);
  chart.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 300);

  var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", '"loc"');
  var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", '"title"');

  var lines = chart.addSeries(["project"], dimple.bar, [x, y]);


  chart.draw();

  };

</script>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /*
    Use D3 (not dimple.js) to load the TSV file
    and pass the contents of it to the draw function
    */
  d3.csv("Germany.csv", draw);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**QUESTION**

So as you can see, what I'm trying to do is just read the data in from that file on my GitHub rather than hard coding it- how to do that?

--> Could this possibly have something to do with the size of the file being too large for the bounds of the svg? I kind of doubt it, because I've been trying with small subsets of that `Germany.csv` file and encountering the same issue.

---

I was once told that it would be possible manipulate the data using a variable as I've done with the first example above, something like:

```
var data;

d3.csv("nameOfCsv.csv", function(thisData) {
      data = thisData;
    }
```

but in fact that code snippet doesn't work, for starters it's missing a `)`, and I've never gotten anything like it to work before- so- I'm not sure that it's a reasonable way to go.

### --------------------

---

**UPDATE** @MauricioPoppe solved it, but the sizing is a bit wonky, is there a way to make the look better dynamically, maybe with css or something?

[image]

Comment: no that can't be right, because I can see it with `console.log(data);`. If I knew exactly wasn't working I wouldn't have posted this question

Comment: @JSBob, hi man- sorry for being kind of ... *snarky*, I get so frustrated when I'm programming! haha- but I drank some tea, and I posted a more complete description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your csv shows that each field is wrapped inside a single space therefore instead of

```
var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", '"loc"');
var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", '"title"');
```

You should use

```
var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", ' "loc" ');
var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", ' "title" ');
```

```js
function draw(data) {

  "use strict";
  var margin = 75,
    width = 9000 - margin,
    height = 600 - margin;

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin)
    .attr("height", height + margin)
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chart');


  var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
  chart.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 300);

  var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", ' "loc" ');
  var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", ' "title" ');

  var lines = chart.addSeries(["project"], dimple.bar, [x, y]);


  chart.draw();

};

d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/bookish-adventure/master/data/Germany.csv', draw)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ...but if you don't mind, do you know how to make it so that the indices are legible? should I use css or something?

Comment: you're setting the width to 500px, you should set it based on the amount of data instead e.g. `chart.setBounds(100, 100, data.length, * k 300)` where k should be the height of the label + some margin

Comment: what do you mean by label? I think you mean `k * 300`, is it?

Comment: sorry I meant `chart.setBounds(100, 100, data.length * k,  300)` and for label I meant the text that appears on the x-axis which for you it's `"loc"`

Comment: hmmm, but do you perhaps know how can I get access to that, I guess the number of `" loc" `s is it?

Comment: the number of rows is `data.length` if you have multiple rows with the same `loc` you need to preprocess the data first